# Custom Loss Function Semantic Segmentation Task

Tags: pytorch, image-segmentation, loss-function, loss

I have written a custom loss function where I want to USE a distance based loss such as Hausdorf or Lovasz loss. It is a binary segmentation task where the final activation function is sigmoid. I am finding that although these loss functions decrease the IOU also decreases.

Is there anything incorrect in these blocks of code that could be causing this?

```
class HausdorffDTLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HausdorffDTLoss, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, pred, target):
        batch_size = pred.size(0)
        total_loss = 0

        for i in range(batch_size):
            hausdorff_loss = self._hausdorff_loss(pred[i].unsqueeze(0), target[i].unsqueeze(0))
            total_loss += hausdorff_loss

        return total_loss / batch_size

    def _hausdorff_loss(self, pred, target):
        p = pred
        d1 = self._euclidean_distance_map(p)
        d2 = self._euclidean_distance_map(1-p)
        nd1 = self._normalized_distance_map(d1, p)
        nd2 = self._normalized_distance_map(d2, 1-p)
        dt1 = self._transformed_distance_map(p, nd1)
        dt2 = self._transformed_distance_map(1-p, nd2)
        h1 = self._hausdorff_distance(p, dt2)
        h2 = self._hausdorff_distance(1-p, dt1)
        return torch.max(h1, h2)


    def _hausdorff_distance(self, pred, target):
        return torch.max(pred * target)

    def _normalized_distance_map(self, d, p):
        d = d/(torch.max(d)*2)
        d = torch.min(d, p)
        return d
    
    def _euclidean_distance_map(self, pred):
        # convert tensor to numpy array and move it to cpu
        pred_np = pred.cpu().detach().numpy()

        # binarize the prediction array with a threshold of 0.5
        binary_pred = (pred_np >= 0.5).astype(np.uint8)

        # set all zeros (background) to maximum 8-bit value, 255
        binary_pred[binary_pred == 0] = 255

        # apply OpenCV's distance transform to compute the distance map
        # DIST_L2 is Euclidean distance, and 5 is the mask size
        dist_map = cv2.distanceTransform(binary_pred, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)

        # convert the numpy array back to torch tensor
        # and move it to the device where pred tensor resides
        dist_map = torch.from_numpy(dist_map).to(pred.device)

        return dist_map






    def _transformed_distance_map(self, pred, nd):
        return 0.5 * (pred ** 2) * (4 * nd ** 2 + 1)
```

```
class LovaszLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ignore_index=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.ignore_index = ignore_index

    def forward(self, logits, labels):
        return lovasz_hinge_flat(logits, labels, self.ignore_index)
    
# Initialize the loss function and ignore class 0
lovasz_loss = LovaszLoss()


def lovasz_hinge_flat(logits, labels, ignore_index):
    logits = logits.contiguous().view(-1)
    labels = labels.contiguous().view(-1)
    if ignore_index is not None:
        mask = labels != ignore_index
        logits = logits[mask]
        labels = labels[mask]
    errors = hinge(logits, labels)
    errors_sorted, perm = torch.sort(errors, dim=0, descending=True)
    perm = perm.data
    gt_sorted = labels[perm]
    grad = lovasz_grad(gt_sorted)
    loss = torch.dot(F.elu(errors_sorted) + 1, grad)
    return loss

def hinge(pred, label):
    signs = 2 * label - 1
    errors = 1 - pred * signs
    return errors

def lovasz_grad(gt_sorted):
    p = len(gt_sorted)
    gts = gt_sorted.sum()
    intersection = gts - gt_sorted.float().cumsum(0)
    union = gts + (1 - gt_sorted).float().cumsum(0)
    jaccard = 1 - intersection / union
    if p > 1:  # cover 1-pixel case
        jaccard[1:p] = jaccard[1:p] - jaccard[0:-1]
    return jaccard
```